# Different Apache index options for parent directory and its subdirectories

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to see an Apache-generated index list of subdirectories in reverse date order (most recently modified at the top). I have achieved this with:

```
<Directory "/Users/myDir">
    IndexOptions +FancyIndexing +HTMLTable
    IndexOrderDefault Descending Date
</Directory>
```

However, within these subdirectories I want to see the files in ascending alphabetical order (A-Z).

Is it possible without putting .htaccess files in every single one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Even using `DirectoryMatch` (which doesn't allow the `$` regex), anything a parent is setup with will automatically get inherited by any subdirectories unless you specifically override them.

You can do this either using an htaccess file or you can use a separate `DirectoryMatch` container. Maybe something like:

```
<Directory "/Users/myDir">
    IndexOptions +FancyIndexing +HTMLTable
    IndexOrderDefault Descending Date
</Directory>

<DirectoryMatch "/Users/myDir/[A-Za-z0-9]+/">
    IndexOptions +FancyIndexing +HTMLTable
    IndexOrderDefault Ascending Date
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Comment: Thx great answer, DirectoryMatch worked fine for me. I am using the RegEx `<DirectoryMatch "/Users/myDir/[\w\W]+">` and I added `IndexOptions +IgnoreCase`